# motion estimation by FS-LBP

Tags: video-processing, motion, estimation, lbph-algorithm

I want to do the motion estimation by the method of FS-LBP, but I need to find NNMN.I dont understand the ⊗ symboll. 
                This formule is  NNMN(m, n) =∑∑LBPt(i,j) ⊗ LBPt−1(i + m, j + n). 
                       − s ≤ m, n ≤ s − 1
LBPt is current image. LBPt-1 is reference image frames(previous image). where LBPt and LBPt−1 are the LBP transforms for the current and the reference frames
respectively, and s is the search range.NNMN captures the number of mismatching neighbors
around the central pixel of a macro-block in the current frame and the reference frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

⊗  seymboll is xor operation.
NNMN , for each pixel there are 8 bits of information about its 8 neighbors.Recreate the search block -+16 (search block size is 48) in the LBPt-1 .Devide the LBPt by macro block. Macro blok size (16,16).And scan macro block on search block to find max similarity.